# Impact of Scottish Independence on Expats

Tags: uk-visa, brexit

What will happen to expats (Indian working on Tier 2 General UK Work visa) residing in Scotland if Scotland becomes independent post brexit ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s impossible to answer until eg a) Brexit has happened; b) Scotland has held an Independence referendum that results in a ‘leave’ majority; and c) the terms of independence have been agreed and legislation passed. Given the agonies of Brexit, it seems safe to assume the process will take several years, if it happens at all in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Scottish independence is so hypothetical at this point that there hasn't been a great deal of discussion on the broad terms, let alone on smaller details like establishing an independent immigration territory in Scotland. Most likely, Scotland would honor existing UK visas and/or convert them automatically into visas in a new Scottish immigration system (which would presumably be essentially identical in its initial form). But this is all speculation. There's nothing really concrete to say except that Scottish independence is unlikely to happen before your immigration status changes.

Answer (score 2):

No realistic answer can be given to this question due to the amount of unknown factors at present.

Until the legislation passed in known after a Scottish independence, one could only speculate.

So any speculation now, would not result in an answer that one could rely on.